# What is the proper way to login via email for custom user model?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

I don't need to let users login using usernames, only email.
So I have custom user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    accepted = models.BooleanField('status', default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        'staff status',
        default=False,
        help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this site.',
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        'active',
        default=True,
        help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
                  'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.',
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = MyUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
```

Custom manager:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

And I am using `auth_views.login` method to render login template.
In template I have two input fields named `email` and `password`.

But when I submit form I got a validation error that says the username field is required.

I figured out that `auth_views.login` is using `AuthenticationForm` where `username` field is configured. So I decided to override this form and pass it to the view:

```
class MyAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.EmailField()

url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'authentication_form': MyAuthForm}, name='login')
```

And in the template I use `username` as a name to the email field. That one smells bad.

So my question is am I doing implementation of logging in via email correctly? If not, what is the proper way?

Update: add settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'base:home'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but it is easier to use a third party authentication system instead of writing your own, such as django-allauth

Comment: Can you share `settings.py` from the project (without credentials)?

Comment: @AbbasovAlexander, done

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of all this is to let users login with their email, then this can be done without all this.

Use the django default `User` model. Add a view and a form(with fields email and password) for user login. In your view, after you get user's email, query django's `User` model for his/her username.

Use built-in functions like `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` and `django.contrib.auth.login` in your view to login the user.

Comment: Hm, thanks! It looks like I definitely overdone with this. I'm gonna check your advice later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are in the right direction. Very difficult to answer on your question without deep into project and debugging.

Pay attention to the following parts of Django. When your login form is sent then [`LoginView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d7b9aaa366dd54ecc3142c588162e3adc7c2f7ac/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L43) will pass data to [`AuthenticationForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d7b9aaa366dd54ecc3142c588162e3adc7c2f7ac/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L143). The `AuthenticationForm` call [`def authenticate()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d7b9aaa366dd54ecc3142c588162e3adc7c2f7ac/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L64) that looks at all backends from `settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.

Now, you have one default backend [`ModelBackend`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d7b9aaa366dd54ecc3142c588162e3adc7c2f7ac/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L7). You need to add own backend and add to `settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` .You can have any number of backends, but sequence does matter. For example:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'your_project.backends.CustomBackend',  # will be called before the next
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Example:

```
class CustomBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, **kw):
        # here you have to return user object or None
        ...

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```